# Changing layouts and java

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have to xml layouts main and info and two java files a main and info 
when the user clicks a button to send them to the info.xml i would like my program to use the info.java 
how is this possible?

Comment: you need to learn the basics. http://developer.android.com/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the 'info' Activity
2. Register it in the manifest
3. Set the layout of this 'info' Activity to your info.xml
4. Start this Activity by calling `startActivity(MainActivity.this, Info.class )` in the `onClickListener` of your button

Comment: @turokevie It means, create an xml, `info.xml` and in `info.java`, inside `onCreate()` write `setContentView(R.layout.info);`

Comment: I get this error message                                             The method startActivity(Intent, Bundle) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, Class<Info>)